# Parsing single quoted string with parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying to build a parser that singly quoted strings using the following code:

```
def colValue = (NULL | boolean | decimalNumber | "'" ~> """[^']*""".r <~ "'")
```

The problem is that of course this does not match a string that contains `\'`, not even with the slash in front. But this does match `'hello hello'`, but not `'hello\'hello`

Is there any way to parse a singly quoted string? I am using `JavaTokenParser` but I cant use `stringLiteral` because chars are not escaped with `\\` and are not enclosed in double quotes.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are probably several ways to achieve this, but one way would be using a lookbehind in your regex in order to match `'` when preceded by `\`.

```
def quotedStr = "'" ~> """([^']|(?<=\\)')*""".r <~ "'"
```

This leaves the `\`s in the output, which you could remove afterwards:

```
def quotedStr =
  "'" ~> ("""([^']|(?<=\\)')*""".r ^^ ((_: String).replace("\\'","'"))) <~ "'"
```

Comment: I would not need to remove the slash from the input, I need the input as is, but this still does not work and the regex does not match my string, like `'hello \' hello'`

Comment: That's odd, because it works for me: `parse(quotedStr, """'hello \' hello'""")` returns `res1: Parsers.ParseResult[String] = [1.17] parsed: hello, \'world`

Comment: To make it work it needs to have two \, like "'hello \\' hello'".
So, the problem is that, to scala, my input is just like `'hello ' world'`, and I need to get everything, `hello ' world`